How should deferred assertions behave in a combinatorial testbench?
Consider the following SystemVerilog snippet.
program p;
    initial begin
        for (int i = 0; i != 100; ++i) begin
            test.pass = i;
            /* verilator lint_off ZERODLY */
            #0;
        end

        #1;
    end
endprogram

module test;
    integer pass;
    p pp();

    always_comb
        assert #0 ((pass % 2) == 0)
            $display("pass %d", pass);
        else
            $display("fail %d", pass);
endmodule

Here, odd values of pass should cause the assert to fail. Based on my understanding of the language (I'm reading IEEE  1800-2023), a simulator should print a hundred lines of alternating pass/fail messages, like this:
# fail           x
# pass           0
# fail           1
# pass           2
# fail           3
# pass           4
# fail           5
# pass           6
# fail           7
...

My reasoning is thus:

The always block in the module will execute in the Active region every time pass changes.
The assert condition will be checked and one of the action blocks (either $display("pass") or $display("fail")) will be added to the "deferred assertion report queue". The queue could potentially be flushed and the always block re-executed several times.
Eventually, the Active region will be drained, the simulation will move to the Observed region, at which point exactly one action block will be in the queue. The action block will mature and will be scheduled to the Reactive region.
In Reactive, a line of text will be printed.
Re-Inactive will become Reactive and the program's initial block will resume, changing pass and suspending. This will cause the initial block to be scheduled to Re-Inactive and the always block to Active.
The whole process repeats.

However, Questa, Riviera, and Verilator all more or less agree on printing this:
# fail           x
# fail          99

Which leads me to believe I'm missing something. What is it?

Because you are iteratively changing pass in a re-active/re-inactive loop in a program block , the alway_comb in the module only sees one change of pass in the active region.

always_comb executes its deferred assertion  unconditionally once at time 0 in the active region. It puts a failure (pass is still x)in the observed region report queue.
The observed region flushes the failure action to the reactive region.
The reactive region begins. There is actually a race condition whether the action block prints the failure with pass x prior or prints 0 because the first iteration of the for loop executes prior.
The for loop iterates over the re-active and re-inactive regions changing pass
After the for loop finishes, the always_comb executes again in the active region. pass is now 99. That triggers the second assertion failure in the report queue.
A second iteration of the observed region executes and flushes another failure action block report.
A second re-active region executes, displaying the failure.

Because of the mixture of modules and program blocks, the observed region executes twice. I strongly suggest never using program blocks.

Thank you! I completely missed the fact that not only must the entire Reactive region be drained before moving on, the entire reactive region set must be drained before moving on to Active. That also probably means that my attempts at completely getting rid of the concept of time when testing combinatorial modules are in vain.

I don't think there's a race though. The value of pass in $display(pass) should be captured at the point of queueing (in Active) and that value should be printed even if the action block executes in Reactive, possibly after pass was modified.

While this resolves my confusion regarding the snippet in question, it creates a different confusion for me. Could you please have a look at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/728081/why-does-active-region-process-execute-during-programs-0-in-questa as well?
