Why does active-region process execute during program's #0 in Questa?
Consider the following snippet.
program p;
    initial begin
        for (int i = 0; i != 100; ++i) begin
            test.reflag = i[0];
            /* verilator lint_off ZERODLY */
            #0;
            assert(test.flag == !i[0])
                $display("pass %d, %d, %d", i, test.flag, test.reflag);
            else
                $display("fail %d, %d, %d", i, test.flag, test.reflag);
            #0;
        end

        #1;
    end
endprogram

module test;
    p pp();

    logic flag, reflag = 0;
    always_comb
        flag = !reflag;
endmodule

I think the assert should fail, the expected output is:
pass           0, 1, 0
fail           1, 1, 1
pass           2, 1, 0
fail           3, 1, 1
pass           4, 1, 0
fail           5, 1, 1

My reasons are:

test.reflag = i[0]; is executed in Reactive region, since it's a program-scope statement. The update of reflag schedules the always_comb block to Active.
#0 suspends the initial process and schedules it to Re-Inactive.
The entire reactive region set must be drained before Active processes can resume, therefore, always_comb is NOT executed at this point. Instead, the initial process is resumed.
The assert is executed and fails.

However, in Questa, the assertion is not triggered. The output is this:
# pass           0, 1, 0
# pass           1, 0, 1
# pass           2, 1, 0
# pass           3, 0, 1
# pass           4, 1, 0
# pass           5, 0, 1

It does get triggered in Verilator. Riviera will not allow me to use a blocking assignment in program scope (is that a restriction that was lifted in later version of the standard?) and changing it to non-blocking will cause both Riviera and Questa to correctly fail the assertion.
What's going on?

This is likely a tool bug. Both program blocks and procedural #0delays are constructs to be avoided.

The SystemVerilog LRM IEEE Std 1800-2023 § 24.2 states program blocks provide a syntactic context that specifies scheduling in the reactive region. § 24.4 goes on describing the intent of the program block is to eliminate some sources of a race condition. However, in practice it adds a layer of complexity, and in some cases adds new race conditions.
IEEE Std 1800-2023 § 4 describes all the scheduling regions. Figure 4-1 (directly above § 4.5) shows the relations and execution order of the regions.
Your modules runs in the active region; the program block runs in the reactive region. The #0 in the program block is not in the Inactive region, but the Re-Inactive region. As the scheduling is defined, the program block will complete its for-loop before the re-entering the Active region where module is allowed to react.
If you are unable to get a copy of IEEE Std 1800-2023, then I recommend finding an older version. The scheduling semantics has remained the same.

I agree that the for loop execution should not be interleaved execution in Active. My problem is that I'm seeing a different behavior in the simulator. I do have the standard, it's free through IEEE Get.
